# How can I move the product text under the product photos? I am only using HTML and CSS. As soon as I change it away from Flex, the images get too big

Tags: html, css

How can I move the product info under the product pics?
I am only using HTML and CSS. As soon as I change it away from Flex, the images get too big.

Please see what it looks like in the picture below.

**html**

```
    <div id="newProductsBox">
    
        <img class="productPic" src="img.jpg" alt="blue beanie">
        <div class="productInfo">
          <p class="productName">Beanie blue</p>
          <p class="productPrice">29,99 €</p>
          <p class="NEWicon">NEW</p>
        </div>

        <img class="productPic" src="img.jpg" alt="brown beanie">
        <div class="productInfo">
          <p class="productName">Beanie brown</p>
          <p class="productPrice">29,99 €</p>
          <p class="NEWicon">NEW</p>
        </div>

        <img class="productPic" src="img.jpg" alt="green beanie">
        <div class="productInfo">
          <p class="productName">Beanie green</p>
          <p class="productPrice">29,99 €</p>
          <p class="NEWicon">NEW</p>   
        </div>

        <img class="productPic" src="img.jpg" alt="black beanie">
        <div class="productInfo">
          <p class="productName">Beanie black</p>
          <p class="productPrice">29,99 €</p>
          <p class="NEWicon">NEW</p>
        </div>

    </div>
```

**css**

```
#newProductsBox {
  display: inline-flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 170px;
}

img {
  .productPic {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
}
```

[image: what it looks like now...]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bring the picture into productInfo class.

like this way:

```
 <div class="productInfo">
        <img class="productPic" src="img.png" alt="blue beanie">
          <p class="productName">Beanie blue</p>
          <p class="productPrice">29,99 €</p>
          <p class="NEWicon">NEW</p>
 </div>
```

Comment: Thank you. But then my images get really big! What would you suggest?

Comment: Try reducing the height and width to 80%  or maybe 70% and see if it works.

Answer (score 1):

Brought the picture into productInfo class and then resized the images.